# op-amp amplifier for small loop antenna

Tags: operational-amplifier, antenna, radio

I’m trying to make myself a ferrite core loopstick antenna for a crystal radio project so I’ve pulled the ferrite rod out of an old radio. The rod is about 1.5 inches and I’ve wound my own coil around it. I want it to be a medium wave antenna and I’m trying to figure out the number of turns, etc. by trial and error.

Anyway, I had envisioned that I would be able to connect the terminals of the coil to my DMM and see some kind of voltage, just so I would know the antenna works. When I tried this, nothing registered. I suspect that my multimeter doesn’t have high enough resolution for the small voltage of the antenna.

I don’t have access to an oscilloscope or anything fancy, but I do have op-amps. I’m thinking maybe I could amplify the signal with an open loop amplifier or something. I’m not really great with op-amps, so I’m not sure what that would look like. If I just connect the coil terminals to the op amp inputs, would that work? Another constraint is that I don’t have a good power supply, just batteries so I have no way to supply a negative voltage for Vee. I would probably just use ground for the negative supply voltage because I don’t care if the signal is missing the negative side I just want to see that it’s there.

Comment: I would put an envelope detector behind the antenna (which should have a parallel capacitor) and measure there. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_detector

Comment: A DMM probably isn't going to be sensitive enough.  Take all the turns that you removed from that antenna, and put 'em back on -- that should be about right.

Comment: Search on "medium-wave antenna preamp" or "AM Radio antenna preamp".  An op-amp isn't the best choice for this.  A typical "jelly bean" op-amp with a gain bandwidth product of 10MHz will only have an open-loop gain of 20 or so at 500kHz, so the characteristics of the complete amplifier will be crappy.  On the other hand, a 2N2222 or 2N3904 transistor has an \$f_T\$ in excess of 100MHz, and should be good for 10 or 20dB of gain.

Comment: This is an application for a grid dip meter.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your setup, the voltage may be moving faster than what the DMM can measure (check the datasheet to see what the frequency cutoff is). DMM's also have long cables/probes that have lots of inductance and physically limit the response to the MHz range or lower. So if your trying to measure a higher frequency than that, an oscilloscope will be necessary, there are cheap USB oscilloscopes on the market that go up to 200MHz.

You'll also probably need to gain up the signal. In this case connect an [op amp with a gain of 10 or 100](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/analogue_circuits/operational-amplifier-op-amp/gain-equations.php) with a higher gain bandwidth product than the signal you want to observe.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, which will provide about 100X gain:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fObEJh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

C3 is optional, to experiment with tuning.